# Biber doesn't compile bibliography with year field

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, biber

The following minimal example doesn't compiles on macOs with `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)` and `biber 2.14`.

If I remove the `year` fields from the bib file, it works.

Any ideas, what's wrong here? The same example works on another Mac with previous version of pdflatex and biber (TeX Live 2019)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lauraPhd2016.bib}
\begin{document}
I doubt that there is any useful information here~\cite{wikibook}.

All we know is limited, apart from knowing the answer we all know. 
Or do we? Wombat and Koala have discovered some interesting things~\cite{wombat2016}.

Some people are too nosy. What can happen to them is described by Laura Lion~\cite[9]{lion2010}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

```
@article{wombat2016,
    author   = {Walther Wombat and Klaus Koala},
    title    = {The true meaning of 42},
    journal  = {Journal of modern skepticism},
    year     = {2016},
    keywords = {trusted},
}
@book{lion2010,
    author       = {Laura Lion and  Gabrielle Giraffe and Carl Capybara},
    title        = {The dangers of asking the wrong question},
    publisher    = {publishing house},
    year         = {2010},
    keywords     = {trusted},
}
@online{wikibook,
    title        = {Generating Bibliographies with biblatex and biber},
    organization = {Wikibooks},
    url          = {https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Generating_Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber},
    keywords     = {untrusted},
}
```

I ran the following commands:

```
pdflatex document
biber document
pdflatex document
pdflatex document
```

The log file (`document.blg`):

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.14
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'document.blg'
[102] biber-darwin:322> INFO - === Di Okt 20, 2020, 10:19:46
[128] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'document.bcf'
[252] Biber.pm:943> INFO - Found 3 citekeys in bib section 0
[269] Biber.pm:4256> INFO - Processing section 0
[270] Utils.pm:75> INFO - Globbing data source 'lauraPhd2016.bib'
[270] Utils.pm:91> INFO - Globbed data source 'lauraPhd2016.bib' to lauraPhd2016.bib
[283] Biber.pm:4455> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'lauraPhd2016.bib' for section 0
[285] bibtex.pm:1653> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[290] bibtex.pm:1471> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'lauraPhd2016.bib'
```

Comment: compiles fine here on windows, but I have Biber 2.15 not 2.14. Perhaps you have this issue: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/324

Comment: `rm -rf \`biber —cache\`` did the trick!